# challenge writing generic functions in c#

Tags: c#, generics, frameworks, entity

I have a function with the following signature

```
string[] GetUserRoleIdsWithAccess<TEntity, T>(TEntity entity) where TEntity 
: IEntity<T>, IAclSupported;
```

I tried using it in another function like this

```
 _aclService.GetUserRoleIdsWithAccess(entity).ToList();
```

where entity is defined in a function as below :

```
void PrepareModelUserRoles<TModel, TEntity, T>(TModel model, TEntity entity, bool ignoreAclMappings)
        where TModel : IAclSupportedModel where TEntity : IEntity<T>, IAclSupported
```

however, i keep getting

```
The type arguments for method 
'IAclService.GetUserRoleIdsWithAccess<TEntity, T>(TEntity)' cannot be 
inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Please what can I be doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly stating the generic parameters in the calling code? `_aclService.GetUserRoleIdsWithAccess<T1, T2>(entity).ToList();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of C#'s type inference. To fix this you should pass in the type explicitly, as mentioned in the comment on your question:

(Replace T1 and T2 with the correct type)

```
_aclService.GetUserRoleIdsWithAccess<T1, T2>(entity).ToList();
```